# How to switch an AC signal

Tags: mosfet, switches, ac, amplitude-modulation

I have two AC signals, and I want to control their flow (either allow them to pass or open the circuit), therefore, I can imagine that the solution to my problem could be the same for both of these signals (although they are different). I hope I will be able to explain this well, but please let me know if there is anything I can add.

**Signal 1:** AM signal with the carrier frequency of 3MHz and data frequency of 300kHz. The minimum signal values are  7.8V, 92mA, and the maximum values are 46V, 2.2A.

**Signal 2:** 300kHz signal, where the amplitude varies due to the distance between the inductive coils that I am using as a channel to transfer and receive the signals. The signal strength is between 42V, 1.1A, and 310mV, 75mA.

I am new to working with AC signals, therefore, I went through multiple failures. Initially, I thought of using P-channel MOSFET as a switch by controlling the gate with MCU (3.3V). That would be a failure since both are AC signals, therefore, the Vgs will be changing. Another option would be a relay, but at this moment I have to take into account the size of the system, therefore I would like to look at other options first. Somewhere I read that two MOSFETs can be connected back to back, which creates a solid-state relay, but I was not able to find any useful information about that. Could that be an option I can look into more deeply? And what are the other possibilities for switching these signals?

Any information you can provide me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Almost all discrete MOSFETs have a parasitic anti-parallel diode which means they can only block current one way. You can actually see the diode in some MOSFET symbols. You can't just use one MOSFET to block AC. You need at least two with a bunch of gate drive circuitry. It's not really anything difficult or complicated but probably more than you can handle if you are just starting out. You should probably just use relays.

Comment: Please double-check your question title. I think you have a typo.

Comment: When you say "AC signal", I assume something in the audio/ultrasonic range.  I'd call 3 MHz "RF" (Radio Frequency), and 300 KHz is getting towards RF.  At 3 MHz, you would likely need different techniques than at audio frequencies.

Comment: @DKNguyen What would be the two MOSFET connection logic? I would be glad to look into it.

Comment: Thanks, @PeterBennett. It is also nice to know these kinds of details.

Comment: @DKNguyen do you think something similar as shown in [Figure 12](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva948/slva948.pdf?ts=1628669693100&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) would be a good start?

Comment: That's the basic way to do it.